# Add an array of Movie Clips to a filter ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, effects

i stored 8 mc's in an array an i put them on the stage.
now I want to apply to these mc's a blur effect.
My problem is that i don't know how to apply for every mc the blur effect by clicking on it.
So for example I have all the mc's on the stage and if I click on one of them the clicked one should have the blur effect and so on.
How to apply the filter to the mc's?
Thank you for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the mc's array and add event listeners on each of them:

```
var mcArrayLength:int = mcArray.length();
for (var i:int = 0; i < mcArrayLength; i++) {
  var mc:MovieClip = mcArray[i] as MovieClip;
  mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMcClick);
}
```

and the event handler:

```
function onMcClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var clickedMc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
  clickedMc.filters = [myBlurFilter];
}
```

of course, if you wanted to have only one blurred mc at a time, you should keep a reference to it and remove blur once another mc is clicked:

```
var currentlyClickedMc:MovieClip;

function onMcClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var clickedMc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
  clickedMc.filters = [myBlurFilter];
  if (currentlyClickedMc) currentlyClickedMc.filters = [];
  currentlyClickedMc = clickedMc;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors with this code? Have you properly defined `BlurFilter`'s properties to see a visual difference of clicked MC? Can you show full source code?

Comment: i have done it. i have a problem with "currentTarget" and ".target"
so it only works if I use "target" and not "currentTarget".
could you probabilly explain me how to make the parenting for my mc's?
i mean the mc that is clicked should be in foreground.

Comment: Lets say your MC's have a parent called `container`. In that case, everytime a MC's is clicked, you should re-add this MC to the parent (this moves the MC to the top of the display list). This code should go inside `onMcClick` function: `container.addChild(clickedMc)`

Comment: can you tell me how to assign to every mc a number beacuse when the mc's are in the right order on the grid something should be displayed.
or if you have an ideea how i can do that
thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. But for simple numbering, you could set MC's `name` property to desired number, converted to `String`, for example: `myMC.name = myNumber.toString();`

Comment: i use this mC's as puzzle pieces and i want that when the mc's are in the correct positions something should be displayed like "End" or something like that

Comment: i have a grid on the stage and I have an ideea how to make this but I donn't know if it will work.
I want to use "dropTarget to see if the right puzzle piece was droped on the right grid part. And I thougt to assign numbers to the grid parts and to the mc's: for example if the puzzle piece nr.1 was droped on the grid part nr.1 and so on and if all all puzzle pieces are in the correct positions the game should end

Comment: Since you wrote that all these MC's are in array, you could use array index to indentify every MC. For example `array[0]` (note: array elements start at 0) refers to the first MC you added, `array[1]` refers to the second MC and so on... So you can perform this kind of check: `if (mcToBeDropped == array[gridCellIndex]) {//piece is where it belongs } else { //piece dropped in wrong cell }`

Answer (score 0):

something like this (untested) should work:

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.filters.BlurFilter;

    //Class
    public function ClickToBlur
    {
        //Variables
        private var clickableObjects:Array;

        //Constructor
        public function ClickToBlur(clickableObjects:Array)
        {
            this.clickableObjects = clickableObjects;

            init();
        }

        //Initialize
        private function init():void
        {
            for each (var object:Object in clickableObjects)
            {
                object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickMouseEventHandler);
            }
        }

        //Click Mouse Event Handler
        private function clickMouseEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (evt.currentTarget.filters == [])
            {
                evt.currentTarget.filters = [new BlurFilter()];
            }
            else
            {
                evt.currentTarget.filters = [];
            }
        }

        //Dispose
        public function dispose():void
        {
            for each (var object:Object in clickableObjects)
            {
                object.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickMouseEventHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

just pass your array to a new instance of the class

```
var ctb:Object = new ClickToBlur(myArrayOfObjects);
```

and clean up when your done:

```
ctb.dispose();
```

since they're all Movie Clips, you should use a Vector instead of an Array.

Comment: You've got an `=` where you want a `==`

Comment: fixed ;)... but still untested :p